# multiple return values from PHP with jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, return-value

I'm using this jQuery code:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "customerfilter.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
        $(".custName").html(html);
    }
});
```

How can i do something like this: `$(".projDesc").html(html1);`

So i can split the returned results into two html elements?

```
echo "<p>" .$row['cust_name']. "</p>";
```

thats the PHP i'm using and i want to echo another statement which i can put into another HTML element

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use `json_encode()` to convert an associative array from PHP into JSON and use `$.getJSON()`, which will return a Javascript array.

Example:

```
<?php echo json_encode(array("a" => "valueA", "b" => "valueB")); ?>
```

In Javascript:

```
$.getJSON("myscript.php", function(data) {
  alert("Value for 'a': " + data.a + "\nValue for 'b': " + data.b);
});
```

Comment: Do you use the .getJson inside the success function of the ajax post or completely separate of it?

Comment: @Arken I'm not sure what you mean. `getJSON()` takes a URL and success handler function that receives the decoded data as its argument. You needn't call it again in the handler, since the request has already been executed.

Comment: Great hint. I had to add var myData = JSON.parse(response); to convert the response from AJAX success, but same idea (instead of getJSON)

Answer (score 50):

Make your response return JSON, you'll need to change your jQuery to this, so the expected dataType is json:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "customerfilter.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        $(".custName").html(data.message1);
        $(".custName2").html(data.message2);
    }
});
```

Then you need to encode your response as a JSON Array:

```
 <?php echo json_encode(
      array("message1" => "Hi", 
      "message2" => "Something else")
 ) ?>
```

Comment: Should be dataType: 'json'.  You are missing the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you return a [JSON](http://json.org/) object. This way you can easily put many different results inside the ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separator and join the values like this in your response

```
echo $value1.'|'.$value2;
```

Now you can use JavaScript method split("|") as below:

```
var myarray = response.split("|");
var value_1 = myarray[0];
var value_2 = myarray[1];
```