# Assign outside variable with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my **js** page and **tcCheck.php** page.

```
<script>
function checkTC() {

    $("#loaderTC").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "check/tcCheck.php",
    data:'tc='+$("#tc").val(),
    type: "POST",

    success:function(data){
        //WORKING CODE
         document.getElementById('name').value = data;
       //NEEDED CODE
            document.getElementById('name').value = "NAME VARIABLE"
            document.getElementById('phone').value = "PHONE VARIABLE"

    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
</script>
```

**tcCheck.php**

```
<?php
    require_once("../config.php");
    include("../girisbilgi.php");
    $query = $link->query("SELECT * FROM musteri where musteriTC='" . $_POST["tc"] . "' and userSaID='".$userSaID."'");
    if($veri =$query->fetch_object())
    {

     //WORKING CODE
     echo $veri->musteriAD;
     /NEEDED
    $name  =   $veri->musteriAD;
    $phone =   $veri->musteriTel;
    }    
?>
```

tcCheck.php works correctly.I can change input if i change my tcCheck.php result like echo $veri->musteriAD; 
But i need to change 2 inputs so i need this variables.
 How can i assing $name and $phone variable values in my js page ?

Comment: You could send the data back as JSON, XML, or a CSV. You then will need to parse the return in JS. Your SQL is open to SQL injections.

Comment: Agree with @chris85
`$query = $link->query("SELECT * FROM musteri where musteriTC='" . $_POST["tc"] . "' and userSaID='".$userSaID."'");
`
You are exposing yourself to the simpliest SQL Injections ... Never trust user inputs ;) You should escape the value, because it only need *' OR 1+1 '"#*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple return values from PHP with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594265/multiple-return-values-from-php-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I know its open to SQL Injections. Its just sample :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a format you can parse easily with javascript - i would reccomend json:

```
if($veri =$query->fetch_object()){

    //set correct header
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    //echo out json
    echo json_encode(['name'=>$veri->musteriAD, 'phone'=>$veri->musteriTel]);
    //done, stop processing
    die();

}
```

javascript

```
success:function(data){

     $('#name').val(data.name);
     $('#phone').val(data.phone);
},
```